# Update status of record: one record to be active and all other will be inactive

Tags: php, mysql

I have a `enum('Y','N')` field in db table with many records hold the status of record active(`Y`) or inactive(`N`) .

Only one record can be active at a time. An interface is given to show all the records with their status if it is active then it is showing word `Active` if it is inactive a submit button provided to make it active with each record.

Right now I am doing with two update commands

```
update table_name set active="Y" where id=$id
update table_name set active="N" where id != $id
```

My question is:-

Really Do I needs two update command to execute or Is their any update command to update them in once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do

```
 UPDATE table_name
    SET active = 
        CASE WHEN id = $id THEN "Y"
             ELSE "N"
        END
```

Confirm the syntax though - I didn't actually try the code.

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE  table_name
SET     active = IF(id = $id, 'Y', 'N')
WHERE   (id = $id) OR (active = 'Y')
```

This will use the indexes on `id` and `active`.